# Algorithm for arranging patients; simpler version of bin packing

Tags: algorithm, bin-packing

I am currently working on a scheduling tool where I have multiple locations (bins) each with differing seating capacities where I need to place patients. The patients are either positive or negative. I cannot mix positive and negative patients in the same location.

As each requirement to seat a patient comes in I need to be able to state whether we can seat them based on the patient being positive or negative.

There is no requirement to assign a patient to a location so the arrangement of patients can be fluid, I just need to maximize capacity.

At the point of making the calculation I will know:

1. How many locations there are.
2. The number of seats in each location.
3. Number of positive patients already granted a seat.
4. Number of negative patients already granted a seat.

I am sure someone will have a clear solution to this but at the minute I can't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: For the already-seated patients, do you also know at which location they are seated? From here, do you receive a stream of patients, rather than knowing them all ahead of time? Can any seat be occupied by any patient? If so, I don't really see the problem - bin packing is hard because items have different sizes. If they all have the same size, it doesn't really matter where you put them. You just need to decide which location should be negative and which positive - you probably just want to assign the locations from the largest one.

Comment: Each patient is the same "size", correct? So I don't see why you need to do anything more than direct each positive patient to any of the locations with other positive patients and at capacity >= 1, and each negative patient to any of the locations with other negative patients and capacity >= 1. If you get a X-ive (where X is "positive" or "negative") patient and there are no X-ive locations with free capacity, pick the smallest-capacity empty location, which then becomes X-ive.

Comment: I agree the patients are the same size. Let me give an example of the problem I was trying to anticipate.

Lets say we have 3 locations; Location A has a capacity of 3, Location B has a capacity of 4 and Location C has a capacity of 4.

If I have 3 +ive patients in Location A, 4 -ive in Location B and 3 -ive in Location C then if the next patient is +ive I can't accommodate that. However I should be able to if I switch Locations A and C.

Comment: Right, but am I correct in thinking that you don't know the final numbers of +ve and -ve patients?  If you *do* know that, then yes, you will be able to use a smarter (non-greedy) approach to find a better way of allocating patients in cases like your example, but if you don't know that, then I believe the optimal strategy will be to always allocate the smallest available free room when there are no non-full X-ive rooms left -- because this minimises the number of seats wasted in the worst case (which would be when no other X-ive patient comes in afterwards).

Comment: @j_random_hacker It is true that I don't know the final number of patients. However I am free to move patients around therefore I was thinking as each patient requirement comes through I can treat that as if that was the final list and re-evaluate each time.

Comment: If you're free to move patients around then... what exactly are you trying to optimise?  Expected number of patient relocations?

Comment: I was hoping there was a standard approach to making as many allocations as possible. Perhaps it is a manual case of trying every permutation. Do you know of known approach to this type of problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If (a) the goal is to move the minimum number of patients around, and (b) you don't know what patients you'll get in the future, then there can never be any net benefit to moving patients around before you absolutely need to -- i.e. before you encounter a patient who has nowhere left to go.  Basically it's optimal to be as "lazy" as possible in moving already-allocated patients.  Or is your goal instead to e.g. always have the maximum number of seats available for patients of either kind?  You have to define the objective function clearly.

Comment: BTW if you write @j_random_hacker in a comment I'll be notified (otherwise I won't and might miss it).

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thank you for your help (and assistance with SO). I think I have a clear picture now of how I will approach this which will be as "lazy" as possible. I think I was over complicating things. I am the only dev here so I think I just needed someone to bounce ideas off. Thanks again!

Comment: @Copers: You're welcome :) I know the feeling BTW!